# String vs String[] in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the values of inputs. I should get an array of strings but instead I only get one string.

Shouldn't `$('input[name="paramDescriptions"]').val();` get all the values of the input where name equals x?

How do I fix this

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {

  var paramDescriptions = $('input[name="paramDescriptions"]').val();
  console.log(paramDescriptions);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputDiv" class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">1</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="LASTNAME"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for LASTNAME" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName1" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">2</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="EXPECTED"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName2" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
</div>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: JQuery .val() definition = "Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element." You would need to just get all elements with name="paramDescriptions" and iterate those and append their val() to string variable.

Comment: isn't there a less code way of doing it?

Comment: yes. use array.map function

Comment: can you make an example as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your node collection of inputs and push each value to string array:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  //Declare array for storing string values
  let myInputValues = [];
  let inputs = $('input[name="paramDescriptions"]');
  //Iterate your collection and push values to string array
  $(inputs).each(function(index, ele){
       myInputValues.push($(ele).val());
  }

});
```

Comment: This is what `.map()` is for (nothing wrong with doing it the long way, just much cleaner to use `.map()`)

Comment: @freedomn-m Agreed. Been used to doing things the way I did in the example but have been trying to change my habits to use .map()

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all your inputs with the name `paramDescriptions` and log the value :

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var descriptions = [];
  $('input[name="paramDescriptions"]').each(function(){
    var paramDescriptions = $(this).val();
    descriptions.push(paramDescriptions);
    console.log(paramDescriptions);
  });
  console.log(descriptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputDiv" class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">1</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="LASTNAME"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for LASTNAME" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName1" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">2</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="EXPECTED"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName2" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
</div>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) here like:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {

  var paramDescriptions = $('input[name="paramDescriptions"]').map(function() {
    return this.value || '';
  }).get();
  console.log(paramDescriptions);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputDiv" class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">1</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="LASTNAME"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for LASTNAME" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName1" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">2</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="EXPECTED"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for EXPECTED" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName2" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
</div>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```